# Place Autocomplete always return unable to load search results

Tags: java, android, api

I want to add to my application the possibility to select a place on maps, so I qualified Google Place Api, I created a fragment inside the xml file like thi

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And this is my code:

```
public class StrutturaEdit extends AppCompatActivity {
    PlacesClient placesClient;
    List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID,
            Place.Field.NAME,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS);

    AutocompleteSupportFragment places_fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ........  

        Places.initialize(this, getString(R.string.google_maps_key));
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

        setupPlaceAutocomplete();
    }

    private void setupPlaceAutocomplete() {
        places_fragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
        places_fragment.setPlaceFields(placeFields);

        places_fragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.i("TAG", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
```

So I can do a search, but I never have a result. I get always "Unable to load results":

[image: search results]

What can i do?

Comment: Probably the `key` is not valid

Comment: Have you enabled library "Google Places API for Android" in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ ?

Comment: @PavelPoley I verified key. For me it's correct. I created after enabling API place, by clicking on "Api Key" and without setting any limitation

Comment: @Dhruv Of course